# How to develop an basic application in mheg technology?

Tags: eclipse

I am new to mheg technology.Is there any tutorials or sample code available to develop a basic app using mheg in Eclipse.

How do I set up the MHEG working Environment in Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

To get MHEG running on your computer, you will need an MHEG simulator to run MHEG source code.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few links which might help you   [MHEG+ Toolkit](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/mhegplus/index.php?title=Main_Page)  this has a compiler and mheg 5 player has well as sample code. also check this  [doc](http://www.scribd.com/doc/3911075/DVB-MHEG-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [brief introduction](http://iangilham.com/2014/03/27/mheg-slate.html) using [MHEGPlus](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mheg-plus/) a while ago. There are other examples in plain MHEG-5 on the web.

You will need a simulator to run the code on your machine. A development environment can be as simple as a text editor, but some of the compilers come with Eclipse plugins that you may find helpful.